# Fullcalendar: Resizing not working when time is enabled on start date

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a json data which contains the start and end date of my event.

```
$(".full-calendar-demo").fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      eventDurationEditable: true, 
      events:[
      {
        id: 83,
        title: "Conference",
        start: '2014-11-12T5:00:00',
        end: '2014-11-13T5:00:00',
      }];
   });
```

How can I enable the resizing of events. I'm using FullCalendar v2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

how about adding resizable:true

Comment: It is not working. There are no resizable: true on documentation.

Comment: how about using refresh event like $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); it is worked for me.